# dynamically generate filesets and use them as parameters

Tags: ant

I want to generate one jar per sub-package using an ant build script on a project looking like this :

```
basepackage
|__ subpackage1
|   |_ Class11
|   |_ Class12
|
|__ subackage2
    |_ Class21
    |_ Class22
...
```

So I have a target `makejar` that should build the jar from a given fileset and a target `makeAll` responsible for making all the filesets and calling the makejar target in these. The problem is that I don't understand **how to build one fileset for each subpackage** and **how to transfer these filesets to the makejar target**.
Is it the good way to do this or should I use an other tool ?
I'd prefer don't using user inputs and parse the directory structure automately.
I've seen a lot of answers talking about `antcontrib` but I don't know if it will solve my problems.